# Svelte, Custom select component not binding correctly

Tags: svelte

I am fairly new to Svelte and trying to understand why my custom select components bindings won't update correctly.

I have an object with two properties, both changed using selects. The options for the second property is dependant on the first property. If I use a regular select directly it works as expected, but using a custom select component with value binding fails seems to miss the update of the property value in the parent component.

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Selector from './Selector.svelte'
    import Select from './Select.svelte'
    
    let option1 = 'a'
    let option2 = 'd'
    
    let result = {
        option1: 'a',
        option2: 'd'
    }
    
    let resultingOptions = []
    
    $: resultingOptions, result.option2 = resultingOptions.includes(result.option2) ? result.option2 : resultingOptions[1]
</script>

<div>
    <div>Values: 1: {result.option1}, 2: {result.option2}</div>
    <div>
        1: <Selector bind:value={result.option1} bind:resultingOptions={resultingOptions} />
    </div>
    <div>
        2: 
        <Select options={resultingOptions} bind:value={result.option2} />
        <select bind:value={result.option2}>
            {#each resultingOptions as option}
                <option value={option}>{option}</option>
            {/each}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Selector.svelte

```
<script>
    import Select from './Select.svelte'
    
  export let resultingOptions = undefined
  export let value
    
  const options = ['a', 'b', 'c']

  $: value, resultingOptions = getResultingOptions(value)

  const getResultingOptions = (value) => {
    switch (value) {
      case 'a':
        return ['d', 'e', 'f']
      case 'b':
        return ['f', 'g', 'h']
      case 'c':
        return ['h', 'i', 'j']
    }
  }

</script>

<Select {options} bind:value={value} />
<select bind:value={value}>
    {#each options as option}
        <option value={option}>{option}</option>
    {/each}
</select>
```

Select.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
  export let options

  export let value

</script>

<select class="select" bind:value={value}>
  {#each options as option}
    <option value={option}>{option}</option>
  {/each}
</select>

<style>
  .select {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
  }
</style>
```

Working (Not working) example can be found here: https://svelte.dev/repl/9afc5ef8be4c4782a7ef0c1e9434cd15?version=3.55.1

Comment: What's to do / which steps to take in the Repl to see the problem?

Comment: If you change the value in either of the selects on the first row the available options for the selects in the second row changes. settings.option2 also gets a new value. This works fine in the second select on the second row (which is a regular select) but doesn't work on the first (which is a custom component). Both have bind:value to the same property so I would assume they should both work.

Comment: Not sure why the select inside the component isn't updated but this seems to be related to the running order. Adding `tick` before updating `result.option2` solves it https://svelte.dev/repl/f9f8eef304d84474b5736a9c02db2387?version=3.55.1 Notice that also the value of option 2 is then correct at the beginning

Comment: Weird indeed. I did not know about the tick function so that could be a workaround to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: I would rather look for a solution that reduces complexity... Here's a version without any reactive statement using the `change` event of the first input https://svelte.dev/repl/55157f2b04394908822ec29302127904?version=3.55.1 Interestingly this also doesn't work correctly if using the `input` event instead. While the order on the element makes a difference with `change` - `bind:value on:change` or `on:change bind:value` - it doesn't with `on:input`